# Jenkins loading external groovy script: powershell and bat steps hanging

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm generating a Jenkins pipeline using a script. This pipeline is then loaded and executed. This works fine on any linux node and with `sh` statements etc.

I have now encountered an issue executing this on a windows node with the `powershell` and `bat` steps:

The checkout scm works fine, but any steps with the `powershell` or `bat` steps hang indefinitely. Copying the data from the generated file and replaying everything in a single Jenkinsfile works as expected.

An example of what is running (excluding the library):

"Main" Jenkinsfile:

```
def pod_label = "my_linux_node"
node(pod_label) {
  stage("Checkout") {
      checkout scm
  }
  stage("Pipeline generation") {
          // genarate pipeline and save in "gen_pipeline.groovy"
  }
  stage("Run Pipeline") {
      pipeline = load "gen_pipeline.groovy"
      pipeline.run_pipeline()
  }
}
```

Script1:

```
def run_pipeline(){
    node('my_win_node') {
       checkout scm
       bat "echo foobar"
    }
}
return this
```